# Regex explanation needed

Tags: regex

My student guideline contains this example.

I need find all **-tation** in **transportation** but for example not **deportation**.
I use regex with lookbehind assertion

```
/(?<=transpor)tation/
```

Also there is an equivalent

```
/tation(?<=transportation)/
```

It says first regex

> is more efficiency because it hasn't backtracking - engine doesn't
>   check tation second time.

Ok. It is good.
And there is obscure phrase for me

> Usually it would either match the text the first time or use a
>   lookahead to check that it match the second pattern instead of
>   backtracking through it a second time with a lookbehind.

I can't understand **both** hints (in particular about lookahead assertion).*(before or and after or)*
I believe my riddle (puzzle) will be clear to native English speaker as a minimum.

Thanks.

Comment: That phrase is really obscure. I think that puzzle can best be solved by the author of that guide. It looks to me like nonsense though. I guess there is a mistake somewhere.

Comment: What it certainly is meant to mean is that the first of the two expressions is more efficient.

Comment: Yes. I also think FIRST hint meant that expression no 1 is more efficient. About SECOND hint: I suppose it says about lookahead, capturing group and programming language (extract from string using backreferences). But it's strange.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't give much thought to it; the statements seem to be based on assumptions about the internal logic of regular expression engines which aren't universally valid.
To shed some light on this, I looked at the debugging info of Perl's regular expression compiler.

[Code](http://codepad.org/CbP0TSHu):

```
use re 'debug';
/(?<=transpor)tation/;
/tation(?<=transportation)/;
```

Output:

```
Compiling REx `(?<=transpor)tation'
size 11 Got 92 bytes for offset annotations.
first at 1
   1: IFMATCH[-8](8)
   3:   EXACT <transpor>(6)
   6:   SUCCEED(0)
   7:   TAIL(8)
   8: EXACT <tation>(11)
  11: END(0)
anchored `tation' at 0 (checking anchored) minlen 6 
Offsets: [11]
    12[8] 0[0] 5[8] 0[0] 0[0] 12[0] 12[0] 14[6] 0[0] 0[0] 20[0] 
Compiling REx `tation(?<=transportation)'
size 13 Got 108 bytes for offset annotations.
first at 1
   1: EXACT <tation>(4)
   4: IFMATCH[-14](13)
   6:   EXACT <transportation>(11)
  11:   SUCCEED(0)
  12:   TAIL(13)
  13: END(0)
anchored `tation' at 0 (checking anchored) minlen 6 
Offsets: [13]
    1[6] 0[0] 0[0] 24[14] 0[0] 11[14] 0[0] 0[0] 0[0] 0[0] 24[0] 24[0] 26[0] 
Freeing REx: `"(?<=transpor)tation"'
Freeing REx: `"tation(?<=transportation)"'
```

Here, the compiled expressions don't seem to be substantially different.